# Project Unavailable error in VS 2010

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am doing an apparently very simple thing ...opening up a solution file in VS 2010.

But the project in the solution fails to load. I see "unavailable" right next to the project name in the Solution Explorer. I right click the project name shown as unavailable and click "Reload project" and for like 1 second the project loads and i see the files in the project and then unloads automatically. Weird...any help is appreciated....

I opened the solution file by clicking the solution file as well as through the "File" menu.

Comment: Is the project folder local? Check permissions?

Comment: The project is in Visual Source Safe (sorry that this is still in use) which sits on a network drive....I just looked and the original project open perfectly fine in "Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate" but the new laptop has "Visual Studio 2010 Shell" - will that make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

missing language support in the VS 2010 shell causes my projects not to load

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2fb335db-6de3-45f3-8960-ca4d75384149/visual-studio-2010-shell-lacks-c-language-support-while-vbnet-is-available